# MSBuild Target - After Solution Build / Rebuild

Tags: deployment, build, msbuild

What way should I go when I want to build some projects and afterwards I want to do some extra stuff? Some kind of finalizing the build.

I need a target that executes just after the last project was build (Rebuild All Succeeded). In that target, some Files including a deployment guide (.docx), some SQL scripts and PowerShell are moved / copied into a predefined directory hierarchy. I already build WSPs and other files that get copied to their destination, but not those "global files".

I thought of the way that after the last project in the build order was build, I can trigger that target, but what if in the future the build order will change?

Is there a "AfterRebuildAll" Target or some best practise?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building with TFS, there are [customizable TFS build targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If you're building with msbuild.exe from the CLI, you can look into placing an "after.solutionfile.sln.targets" msbuild project file in the same folder as your solution that contains your [custom targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee216359.aspx).